# How could I run spacy model (en_core_web_lg) outside the docker file. it makes image too large when I use: RUN python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg

Tags: python, docker, nlp, pycharm, spacy

How could I run spacy model (en_core_web_lg) outside the docker file.

I use: RUN python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg in my Docker file but it makes my container image too large.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How do you intend to use it ?
For example, you could create a command in your workflow that downloads that model and call it as a first step.